# Dynamic Column Headings in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic

I have 2 tables and a stored procedure to display data from them.

Table 1 is **Result** which looks like this:

```
ResultName    ActivityDate     ID

Result1       2013-11-14       1
Result1       2013-11-14       2
Result2       2013-11-14       3
Result3       2013-11-14       4
```

Table 2 is **ResultDetail** which looks like this:

```
ResultName    ActivityDateType

Result1       DateType1
Result2       DateType1
Result3       DateType2
```

When I run my stored procedure to select data from them, I currently have something like this:

```
ResultName    ActivityDateType    ActivityDate    ID

Result1       DateType1           2013-11-14      1  
Result1       DateType1           2013-11-14      2  
Result2       DateType1           2013-11-14      3  
Result3       DateType2           2013-11-14      4
```

I would like to base the ActivityDate column name in my select results on the ActivityDateType when i choose a certain ResultName.

So for example, if I selected just the Result1's I would like it to be:

```
ResultName    DateType1    ID

Result1       2013-11-14   1
Result1       2013-11-14   2
```

I've tried to put it in a variable while joining the tables together and then using the str() function with 
    ActivityDate as str(@ActivityDateType)

but it doesn't work (probably for obvious reasons that I'm not getting)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: If the "Result1" had two different ActivityDateType "DateType1" and "DatetYpe2" you would have both showing up as column and the right values underneath it, right ?

Comment: The ResultDetail table has 1 row per ResultName, there are no duplicates so they will only ever have 1 ActivityDateType

Comment: you need dynamic SQL and PIVOT. in case you want the result filtered for multiple result name the posted sol covers that.

Answer (score 0):

**this is preparing tables as you have.**

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #result
    CREATE TABLE #result
    (   
        resultname      sysname NOT NULL
        ,ActivityDate   DATE NOT NULL
        ,id             INT NOT NULL
    )
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#resultdetail') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #resultdetail
    CREATE TABLE #resultdetail
    (   
        resultname          sysname NOT NULL
        ,ActivityDateType   sysname NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #result( resultname, ActivityDate, id )
                SELECT 'Result1','11/14/2013',1
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'Result1','11/14/2013',2
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'Result2','11/14/2013',3
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'Result3','11/14/2013',4

    INSERT INTO #resultdetail( resultname, ActivityDateType )
                SELECT 'Result1','DateType1'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'Result2','DateType1'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'Result3','DateType2'

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

**This is the Final Query that returns data as you explained.**

**note that i have choose to return the result for "Result1" and "Result3"**

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DynamicColumn_Select') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #DynamicColumn_Select
    CREATE TABLE #DynamicColumn_Select
    (
        ColumnName      sysname NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    )

    /*Prepare the user input for which ResultName we need to generate Final Results*/
    INSERT INTO #DynamicColumn_Select( ColumnName )
    SELECT 'Result1' UNION ALL SELECT 'Result3'

    DECLARE @CsvDynamicColumn_Select NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@CsvDynamicColumn_PvtIn NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

    /*Prepare the Dynamic PIVOT IN Column List as CSV*/
    SELECT @CsvDynamicColumn_PvtIn = 
            CASE WHEN @CsvDynamicColumn_PvtIn = '' 
                THEN '' 
                ELSE @CsvDynamicColumn_PvtIn + ',' 
            END
            + N'['+ActivityDateType+N']'
    FROM
    (
        Select DISTINCT t1.ActivityDateType
        FROM #resultdetail t1
        WHERE resultname IN 
            (SELECT ColumnName FROM #DynamicColumn_Select)
    )qry


    /*Prepare the Dynamic Select Column list as CSV*/
    SELECT @CsvDynamicColumn_Select = 
            CASE WHEN @CsvDynamicColumn_Select = '' 
                THEN '' 
                ELSE @CsvDynamicColumn_Select + ',' 
            END
            + ActivityDateType
    FROM
    (
        Select DISTINCT t1.ActivityDateType
        FROM #resultdetail t1
        WHERE resultname IN 
            (SELECT ColumnName FROM #DynamicColumn_Select)
    )qry

    PRINT @CsvDynamicColumn_PvtIn
    PRINT @CsvDynamicColumn_Select


    SET @SQL = N'
        SELECT resultname,id, '+ @CsvDynamicColumn_Select
        +N'
        FROM
        (
            SELECT resultname,id, '+@CsvDynamicColumn_Select
            +N'
            FROM
            (
                SELECT t1.resultname,t2.ActivityDateType,t1.ActivityDate,t1.id
                FROM #result t1
                JOIN #resultdetail t2
                    ON t1.resultname=t2.resultname
                Where t1.resultname in (Select ColumnName From #DynamicColumn_Select)
            )q1 
            PIVOT
            (MAX(ActivityDate) FOR ActivityDateType IN ('+@CsvDynamicColumn_PvtIn+N'))pvt
        )qry
    '
    PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

**This is a Result of above Query**

[image]